# PHP open another page in iframe POST data

Tags: php, curl, iframe

I am creating an Phonegap app that submits user filled data from a form to my url at www.myDomain.com

so the data sent will be using GET so the url possibilities are like this.

```
www.myDomain.com/processor.php?value1=99
www.myDomain.com/processor.php?value1=ninetyNine
```

I am opening these sites in an iframe.

Now depending on the value and i can get more than 200 different types of values i want to redirect user to some website posting those values

So i can redirect the above two examples like so

```
www.numericProcessor.com       //vlaue send by POST is 99
www.alphabeticProcessor.com    //vlaue send by POST is ninetyNine
```

How do i Go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you're searching for a good design decision?

An easy solution could be to use a switch:

```
<?php
ob_start( );
$value = strip_tags($_GET['value1']);

if (!empty($value )) {
    switch( strtolower($value) ) {
        // add a case for each value you support (in lower case)
        case "99":          $url = "http://www.numericProcessor.com/";     break;
        case "ninetynine":  $url = "http://www.alphabeticProcessor.com/";  break;
        default:            $url = "/InvalidOption.html";                  break;
    }

    header( "location: $url", true, 307 ); // not sure what status you'd prefer
    exit;
}
?>
```

Might this be a good and easy way to do as you wanted? You can then navigate the iFrame to something like www.myDomain.com/processor.php?value1=99

*Please check the code before running, I haven't had the time to test it.*

EDIT:

After our chat I think we solved the problem. This untested piece of code might do the trick for you!

```
<?php  
    $value = strip_tags($_GET['value1']); 

    if (!empty($value )) { 
        switch( strtolower($value) ) { 
            // add a case for each value you support (in lower case) 
            case "99":         $url = "http://www.numericProcessor.com/";    break; 
            case "ninetynine": $url = "http://www.alphabeticProcessor.com/"; break; 
            default:           $url = "/InvalidOption.html"; break; 
        } 

        print " <h1>Please wait while we refer you to the right website</h1>
                <form method='post' action='$url'>
                    <input type='hidden' value='$value' name='<here the name they expact it>'>
                </form>
                <noscript>Please enable JavaScript, else we cannot refer you!</noscript>
                <script language='JavaScript'>
                    document.forms[0].submit();
                </script>";


    }
}
```

*Make sure to test first, as there are probably some dumb mistakes in it.*

Comment: will i be able to send values in POST to the new site?

Comment: Yes, by using the cUrl option `CURLOPT_POST`  you make a request to that page and sending the data of`CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` (Please verify the syntax I thought it was key=value&key=value&....). But note it will not redirect the user. You have to print the result to show the site's content.

Comment: @krv And do I understand well there are only two options? Alpha and numeric values? because you can filter this out by using `is_numeric` and `is_string`. idea: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,  (is_numeric($value) ? 'numeric.com' : 'aplha.com') );`

Comment: no there are different possibilities..what u suggested seems to be working i am  getting the entire Html code of the result of the cURL...how can i feed it into my page..i am using angualrJs in the front end

Comment: @krv Can't you just use `print $result;`? then the content will be displayed in your iframe.

Comment: using srcdoc="dataFormcURL" does the trick but the images are not showing up may be a one of instance or a site specific glitch..now its working

Comment: yes i did that using the srcdoc attribute of the iframe but the images of the resultant page are not loading? Is that commion with cURL return data.?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84808/discussion-between-xyv-and-krv).

Comment: i am getting this "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost/PHP/courierapp/images/index_03.jpg"